# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not worked & not remove a pop_up window

```
function add_comm(){
if($("#fio").val().length>0&&$("#ms_comment").val().length>0){
    $.post('/send.php',{subject:"Комент",message:"FIO: "+$("#fio").val()+"<br /> Comment: "+$("#ms_comment").val()+"<br>"});
    $(".bs-example-modal-sm").modal("show");
    $('.bs-example-modal-sm .modal-content')[0].remove();
    $("#ffrr").html('We call U');
}else{
    alert('Warning');
}
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_comm(); return true;">Send</button>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the code should actually do ?

Comment: remove [0] before .remove(). It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove only the first element, use the jQuery selector:

```
$('.bs-example-modal-sm .modal-content:first').remove();
```

But maybe you should also look at the modal toggle function if you use the bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `[0]` it is going to grab the DOM element itself. DOM elements don't have a `remove()` method. You need the jQuery value. So do instead:

```
$('.bs-example-modal-sm .modal-content').remove();
```

See this JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/skipallmighty/186ztcbh/